# 502 on AWS Cognito ListUsers with PaginationToken

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Using AWSMibileHub to set up my backend. Working on an admin page that shows all the users from AWS Cognito.

I’m using [ListUsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html) to get user list and noticed 502 error on the request with a PagenationToken and it seems to be happening randomly.

In CloudWatch shows this error below.

`InvalidParameterException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'CAISlAIIARLtAQgDEugBADSdLB5dZXQEaQjoL8y8CE1RGGT3PZ4FpCqxFwJkNuhIeyJAbiI6IlBhZ2luYXRpb25Db250aW51YXRpb25EVE8iLCJuZXh0S2V5IjoiQUFBQUFBQUFCZHM4QVFFQmJBZmU5OFgzUnJTM1BHcnYzVmRiVWNScVdIck82VXFZaTdlZklleVRCSEZsYm1ZN01UVTRPV1k0TVRNdE9UYzVZUzAwWTJKakxUazROekl0TkdRek9UYzROMlpoWmpVM093PT0iLCJwcmV2aW91c1JlcXVlc3RUaW1lIjoxNTQzMDkzODIyNDk5fRogNk7FThSKBOuwQGi DoZBnmNN85UY5oFiSAbHWfOzreY=' at 'paginationToken' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\S]+`

Does anybody have the same issue or any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Where do you see this 502?  In the logs from your backend code, or at the browser where you're viewing this admin page?  Can you gather the response headers that accompany the 502?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I see it from front-end on browser. also updated error message from CloudWatch.

Comment: The violation I see is near the end of the token `wQGi<<here>>DoZBnmNN85UY5oFiSAbHWfOzreY=`  There is a space character should not be present.  I suspect you have a token that includes a `+` symbol, and in passing it from front-end to back-end, you are somehow not url-escaping it as `%2B` so it becomes a space.  Are you familiar with how url-escaping (a.k.a. url-encoding) works, and why the `+` symbol requires special handling?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you for the answer. I’m not familiar with it but can do some research now :)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Tried `decodeURI(PaginationToken)` in backend Lambda function but the issue still seems to be occurring. Any idea?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Ended up using `decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(PaginationToken).replace(/%20/g, "+"))` and it seems to be working. Is this okay to use or should I optimize it?

Comment: The net result of what you are doing there is just `.replace(/\ /g,'+')` (change space back to `+`) which is covering for a bug *earlier* in the flow, so it isn't really the correct fix, even though it works.  Without more visibility into how you designed this, I would suggest that you are building a link containing the token that is clicked on at the front-end.  You need to encodeURIComponent this value *before* writing it into the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Store the pagination Token in a variable and then add this `.replace(/\ /g,'+')` to the variable to change the space back to +.

e.g:

```js
const pagination = 'TOKEN FROM COGNITO'.replace(/\ /g,'+')
```

Answer (score 0):

The pagination_token consists of non alphanumeric characters, so its better to encrypt and decrypt when required.

**Encrypt?decrypt utility file**

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const algorithm = "aes-256-ctr";
const password = "sassed";

class Util {

  static encrypt_aes(text) {
    let cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
    let crypted = cipher.update(text, "utf8", "hex");
    crypted += cipher.final("hex");
    return crypted;
  }

  static decrypt_aes(text) {
    let decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password);
    let dec = decipher.update(text, "hex", "utf8");
    dec += decipher.final("utf8");
    return dec;
  }
}

module.exports = Util;
```

**PaginationToken encryption/decription**

```
  const Util = require("./utils");
  class Users {
     static async getUsersAttributes(params) {
        let listparams = {
          UserPoolId: userPoolID /* required */,
          Limit: params.limit || 10,
        };
        if (params.paginationToken) {
          listparams.PaginationToken = Util.decrypt_aes(params.paginationToken);
        }
        let response = await cognitoISPClient.listUsers(listparams).promise();
        response.PaginationToken = Util.encrypt_aes(response.PaginationToken);
    
        return response;
      }
  }
```